# Source of loading value to register or memory

Tags: assembly, initialization, cpu, 8085

When we load a register or memory location with a value (e.g. `MVI 3A` or `MVI 53`), what initializes register or  memory location with that specific value? It is the CPU who performs the initialization, right? But where are those values drawn from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the instruction itself!
An instruction like `mvi A, f1` is encoded as `3E F1`, where the second byte is the operand.

The other `mvi` are similar:

`mvi B, 34` is `06 34`;
`mvi C, AA` is `0E AA`;
`mvi D, 09` is `16 09`;
`mvi E, 53` is `1E 53`;
`mvi H, 00` is `26 00`;
`mvi L, FF` is `2E FF`;
`mvi M, 22` is `36 22`.

When the CPU read the instruction into the decoder register it also read the data into that register. This kind of operands inserted as data into the instruction flow are called *immediates*.